# search list for name and extract id

Tags: r, list

I am using the `gmailr` package in R.

One of the outputs provides a list of the available folders I have in my gmail account.

```
test<-labels(user_id = "me")

test$labels[[1]]

$id
[1] "CATEGORY_PERSONAL"

$name
[1] "CATEGORY_PERSONAL"

$type
[1] "system"
```

From this `test` output, how do I extract the id by searching for the name "Submissions" in my `test` list?

Below is my dput:

`structure(list(labels = list(structure(list(id = "CATEGORY_PERSONAL", 
    name = "CATEGORY_PERSONAL", type = "system"), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "type")), structure(list(id = "Label_4332171194581770179", 
    name = "Weather Data/2018 Data/Individual confirmation", 
    type = "user"), .Names = c("id", "name", "type")), structure(list(
    id = "Label_1", name = "Personal", messageListVisibility = "show", 
    labelListVisibility = "labelHide", type = "user"), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "messageListVisibility", "labelListVisibility", "type"
)), structure(list(id = "CATEGORY_SOCIAL", name = "CATEGORY_SOCIAL", 
    messageListVisibility = "hide", labelListVisibility = "labelHide", 
    type = "system"), .Names = c("id", "name", "messageListVisibility", 
"labelListVisibility", "type")), structure(list(id = "Label_6629457537668286728", 
    name = "Submissions", messageListVisibility = "show", labelListVisibility = "labelShow", 
    type = "user"), .Names = c("id", "name", "messageListVisibility", 
"labelListVisibility", "type")), structure(list(id = "Label_7658051581964161134", 
    name = "Weather Data/2018 Data/Individual Complete", type = "user"), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "type")), structure(list(id = "CATEGORY_FORUMS", name = "CATEGORY_FORUMS", 
    messageListVisibility = "hide", labelListVisibility = "labelHide", 
    type = "system"), .Names = c("id", "name", "messageListVisibility", 
"labelListVisibility", "type")), structure(list(id = "Label_2850739645999054837", 
    name = "Weather Data/2017 Data", type = "user"), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "type")), structure(list(id = "Label_2", name = "Receipts", 
    messageListVisibility = "hide", labelListVisibility = "labelShow", 
    type = "user"), .Names = c("id", "name", "messageListVisibility", 
"labelListVisibility", "type")), structure(list(id = "Label_1014871627782562484", 
    name = "Weather Data/2017 Data/Individual complete", type = "user"), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "type")), structure(list(id = "Label_4", name = "Work", 
    messageListVisibility = "hide", labelListVisibility = "labelShow", 
    type = "user"), .Names = c("id", "name", "messageListVisibility", 
"labelListVisibility", "type")), structure(list(id = "Label_22371230351786854", 
    name = "Weather Data/2018 Data", type = "user"), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "type")), structure(list(id = "IMPORTANT", name = "IMPORTANT", 
    messageListVisibility = "hide", labelListVisibility = "labelHide", 
    type = "system"), .Names = c("id", "name", "messageListVisibility", 
"labelListVisibility", "type")), structure(list(id = "Label_6142857437130093186", 
    name = "Weather Data/2017 Data/individual confirmation emails", 
    type = "user"), .Names = c("id", "name", "type")), structure(list(
    id = "Label_3", name = "Travel", messageListVisibility = "show", 
    labelListVisibility = "labelHide", type = "user"), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "messageListVisibility", "labelListVisibility", "type"
)), structure(list(id = "CATEGORY_UPDATES", name = "CATEGORY_UPDATES", 
    messageListVisibility = "hide", labelListVisibility = "labelHide", 
    type = "system"), .Names = c("id", "name", "messageListVisibility", 
"labelListVisibility", "type")), structure(list(id = "CHAT", 
    name = "CHAT", messageListVisibility = "hide", labelListVisibility = "labelShow", 
    type = "system"), .Names = c("id", "name", "messageListVisibility", 
"labelListVisibility", "type")), structure(list(id = "Label_4351557222970420897", 
    name = "Weather Data", messageListVisibility = "show", labelListVisibility = "labelShow", 
    type = "user"), .Names = c("id", "name", "messageListVisibility", 
"labelListVisibility", "type")), structure(list(id = "SENT", 
    name = "SENT", messageListVisibility = "hide", labelListVisibility = "labelShow", 
    type = "system"), .Names = c("id", "name", "messageListVisibility", 
"labelListVisibility", "type")), structure(list(id = "INBOX", 
    name = "INBOX", messageListVisibility = "hide", labelListVisibility = "labelShow", 
    type = "system"), .Names = c("id", "name", "messageListVisibility", 
"labelListVisibility", "type")), structure(list(id = "TRASH", 
    name = "TRASH", messageListVisibility = "hide", labelListVisibility = "labelShow", 
    type = "system"), .Names = c("id", "name", "messageListVisibility", 
"labelListVisibility", "type")), structure(list(id = "CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS", 
    name = "CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS", messageListVisibility = "hide", 
    labelListVisibility = "labelHide", type = "system"), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "messageListVisibility", "labelListVisibility", "type"
)), structure(list(id = "DRAFT", name = "DRAFT", messageListVisibility = "hide", 
    labelListVisibility = "labelShow", type = "system"), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "messageListVisibility", "labelListVisibility", "type"
)), structure(list(id = "SPAM", name = "SPAM", messageListVisibility = "hide", 
    labelListVisibility = "labelHide", type = "system"), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "messageListVisibility", "labelListVisibility", "type"
)), structure(list(id = "STARRED", name = "STARRED", messageListVisibility = "hide", 
    labelListVisibility = "labelHide", type = "system"), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "messageListVisibility", "labelListVisibility", "type"
)), structure(list(id = "UNREAD", name = "UNREAD", type = "system"), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "type")), structure(list(id = "Label_2707339598948997574", 
    name = "Weather Data/2018 Data/Complete", type = "user"), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "type")), structure(list(id = "Label_8600983624680593897", 
    name = "Weather Data/2017 Data/Complete", type = "user"), .Names = c("id", 
"name", "type")))), .Names = "labels")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use a double `sapply`:

```
sapply(test[sapply(test, `[[`, "name") == "Submissions"], `[[`, "id")
# [1] "Label_6629457537668286728"
```

where

```
sapply(test, `[[`, "name") == "Submissions"
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [19] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

finds cases of "Submissions" and then the outer `sapply` goes over each of the matches and extracts `id`.

I defined `test <- input[[1]]`, where `input` is your provided data (a list of one element).

Another option is

```
na.omit(sapply(test, function(x) if(x$name == "Submissions") x$id else NA))
```

where after checking each element of `test` we immediately return `id`, if there is a match. Then `na.omit` drops the rest of the elements.

Comment: @nak5120, no problem. Added another option.